# Serving images from public folder when using asset pipeline Rails 3.2

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, paperclip, asset-pipeline

I am using Rails 3.2 asset pipeline to serve my assets(images, javascript. css).

I have added paperclip for photo uploads. paperclip by default stores files in `public/system`

When I use the `url` generated by paperclip which is something like

```
/system/users/avatar/000/000/thumb/whatever.jpg
```

It gives me no route error. the file is there at the above location but I think it may be issue with asset pipleline.

Any ideas what might be going wrong ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

just like user451893 said. you should configure your web-server (nginx, apache etc) to deliver all static assets!

in case you don't, then you need to turn on static asset serving in rails:

```
config.serve_static_assets = true
```

have a look at this issue for more details https://github.com/thoughtbot/paperclip/issues/667