# Precompiling assets that are created by model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, sprockets, precompile

I have a question relating to how precompiled assets are utilized in a production environment. What about general file attachments as a part of the model? For example, I have the model "Event". You can have n attachments to the model, and they can be any file you want. Typically they are either image files or PDF files, but they can also be Excel files for example. These files are to be displayed as links to the user and the user can click the link to open the file. The attachment files are stored in the /assets directory in the following manner, alongside the standard assets:

```
/assets
  /images
  /javascripts
  /stylesheets
  /attachments
    /events
      /11
        poster.jpg
        event-details.pdf
```

Now as I understand it, when I run the precompile method, Sprockets generates gzipped/MD5'ed versions of the files to be served...how do I deal with these attachment files? If I run the precompile method, everything gets gzipped...but when I add/remove attachments further down the road through the web interface, some will be gzipped and others won't. What's the best way to deal with this?

Comment: I have never seen any implementation like this before. So, in the example above, the event record with ID 11 has two attachments? How are you saving the files in the asset directory? Are you manually creating these files? I just wonder if you could just use upload attachments, etc. The solution seems bit different....

Comment: I created my own separate model which handles file uploads. Basically whenever I put "has_attachments_dir 'attachments/events'" inside my Event model, any files that exist within '/assets/attachments/events/[id]' are available as attachments to the model instance. Unrelated to this special model, I also store Paperclip attachment photos for my Wine model in /assets/images/pages/wines/:style/:wine_name

Comment: I see. If you insists, then I would recommend you to use public folder instead of assets.

Comment: Why is it then, that Paperclip examples show people using the /assets folder to store attachments?

Comment: I am not sure... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11073650/serving-images-from-public-folder-when-using-asset-pipeline-rails-3-2 may help you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I gave up trying to figure out a way around it and just set all the attachments as well as paperclip attachments to be physically put in the /public directory. From my vantage point, this removes the benefit of compressed assets, but whatever.